# submit form via ng-model having ng-repeat and ng-if

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to submit a form in angular using ng-submit
But I have also used ng-repeat and ng-if in it
Due to which I face the problem of disappearing of input option having ng-model coz of ng-if, my code will make it more clear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <form ng-submit="evaluate(configvalue2)" id="submitanswer" method="POST" >
 <div>
  <div ng-repeat="x in questions[0]">Ques No.{{questions[0].indexOf(x)+1}}
  <br>
  <span class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">{{x.configvalue1}}
  </span><br>
    <div ng-repeat="y in questions[1]">
     <div ng-if="y.configvalue2==x.id">
       <input ng-model='configvalue2' type="radio" value="
        {{y.configvalue3}}" name="{{y.configvalue2}}" >{{y.configvalue1}}
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><hr></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </span>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.evaluate = function(result){
    console.log("submitted value",result);
     }
    $scope.questions = [[{id:1,configvalue1:'myquestionno.1'},
                        {id:2,configvalue1:'myquestionno.2'}],
              [{configvalue2:1,configvalue1:'options1',configvalue3:1},
               {configvalue2:1,configvalue1:'options2',configvalue3:2},
               {configvalue2:1,configvalue1:'options3',configvalue3:3},
               {configvalue2:1,configvalue1:'options4',configvalue3:4},
               {configvalue2:2,configvalue1:'options1',configvalue3:1},
               {configvalue2:2,configvalue1:'options2',configvalue3:2},
               {configvalue2:2,configvalue1:'options3',configvalue3:3},
               {configvalue2:2,configvalue1:'options4',configvalue3:4}

              ]];


                  });
              </script>

        </body>
       </html>
```

Please tell me how to send the input data to the controller

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to send the data of the non-visible inputs as well as the visible ones.

To do that, all you need to do is change `ng-if` to `ng-show` since `ng-if` actually removes the field from the DOM, while `ng-show` only hides it:

```
<div ng-show="y.configvalue2==x.id">
       <input ng-model='configvalue2' type="radio" value="
        {{y.configvalue3}}" name="{{y.configvalue2}}" >{{y.configvalue1}}
</div>
```

Comment: i think the problem is with the ng-repeat inside the  form

Answer (score 0):

To pass your selections to controller, you can do the following:

1. Remove ng-if inside ng-repeat. Instead, use filter on the collections you are repeating

   `<div ng-repeat="y in questions[1] | filter:{configvalue2:x.id}">`
2. As ng-repeat creates an inner scope, you will have to associate ng-model to the scope of parent's parent (as we have 2 ng-repeats here). Also, as we will have different answers to different questions, we ought to be adding respective answer to a collection, indexed by it's question id

   `<input ng-model='$parent.$parent.configvalue[x.id]' type="radio" value="
       {{y.configvalue3}}" name="{{y.configvalue2}}">{{y.configvalue1}}`
3. On the controller-side, you can now access the configvalue collection to find all answers. Passing 'result' to evaluate function is not required.

   `$scope.evaluate = function() {
   alert("submitted values:"+ $scope.configvalue[1] + "," +$scope.configvalue[2]);
   }`

Comment: Curious to know if this helped